# How do you create an instance of an instance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, instances

I want to make unique instances of a set of cars that different people can hold. The cars will have similar base specs but some of their properties and methods will vary.

The problem I have is that I can't work out how this should work. How do you deal with or create instances of instances in JavaScript?

```js
var Car = function(make, country) {
    this.make = make;
    this.country = country;
};

var Ferrari = new Car('Ferrari', 'Italy');

var fred = new Person() {};
var fred.cars['Ferrari'] = new Ferrari(1200, 300000);
```

This causes this error, for obvious reasons. I am aware it is not a constructor (see below).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Ferrari is not a constructor
```

What I am looking for is something like this. Each different instance of a Ferrari will have a different price and milage.

```js
var Ferrari = function(currentPrice, miles) }
    this.currentPrice = currentPrice;
    this.miles = miles;
    // this is an instance of car, aka it needs the result of this:
    // new Car('Ferrari', 'Italy');

};
```

Fred's Ferrari is an instance of Ferrari, which is an instance of Car. The problem is that I can't think of a way to make a constructor build a constructor. Is there a way to do this, or am I just going about this in the wrong way?

**Other Notes:**

I know I could essentially just make each type of car a static JSON-like object and then make instances of that and add new unique values. However, I would like to be able to keep the Car as a constructor so I can easily make more when I need to.

I am clearly missing some understanding of OOP or JavaScript here, but it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: `Ferrari` should be a subclass, not an instance; it should `extends Car`.

Comment: For anyone who was as confused as me, there is a good page on MDN that explains more about how to make an object hierarchy in JS compared to class-based languages: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is a *derived constructor* and associated prototype, sometimes called a *subclass*.

In old-fashioned ES5 it looks like this:

```
var Car = function(make, country) {
    this.make = make;
    this.country = country;
};
var Ferrari = function(currentPrice, miles) {
    Car.call(this, "Ferrari", "Italy");
    this.currentPrice = currentPrice;
    this.miles = miles;
};
Ferrari.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);
Ferrari.prototype.constructor = Ferrari;
```

How that works:

- `Ferrari` is a constructor function that, when called, calls `Car` with `this` referring to the new instance, along with the arguments `Car` needs. `Car` does its thing setting up those properties on the instance. Then we continue with `Ferrari`'s code, which takes the arguments passed in and (in the above) remembers them as properties.
- We ensure that the object that will be assigned to instances by `new Ferrari` (which is taken from `Ferrari.prototype`) uses `Car.prototype` as its prototype object, so that if you add things to `Car.prototype`, they'll be present on `Ferrari`s as well.
- We ensure that the standard `constructor` property on `Ferrari.prototype` refers to `Ferrari`.

Rather nicer in ES2015 (which you can use today via transpilation, such as with tools like [Babel](http://babeljs.io)):

```
class Car {
    constructor(make, country) {
        this.make = make;
        this.country = country;
    }
}
class Ferrari extends Car {
    constructor(currentPrice, miles) {
        super("Ferrari", "Italy");
        this.currentPrice = currentPrice;
        this.miles = miles;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jordão: Thank you! Fixed.

Comment: The ES2015 example looks similar to what I have seen in PHP, but couldn't find a similar feature in Javascript. Thanks!

Comment: It also bears mention that the OP's class model is broken - the `price` and `miles` properties really belong in the base class

Comment: @jamcd: It's relatively new, introduced by the specification from June 2015, which is why you need to transpile if you want to use it in the wild (you don't if you want to use it on current Chrome, or NodeJS). And yeah, it's intentionally similar to similar constructs in other languages (Java, for instance).

Comment: @Alnitak: Thanks. Excuse my ignorance, but is this because they are common properties to multiple different cars? What if you only want to specify a price for some cars and not others?

Comment: @jamcd every car has a price (even if you don't know what it is)

Answer (score -1):

If you want the `Car` instances to be constructors, `Car` must return a constructor.

The problem is that then it will inherit from `Function.prototype` instead of `Car.prototype`. If that's undesirable, use `Object.setProtetypeOf` to fix it:

```
function Person() {
  this.cars = {};
}
function Car(make, country) {
  var instance = function(currentPrice, miles) {
    this.currentPrice = currentPrice;
    this.miles = miles;
  };
  instance.make = make;
  instance.country = country;
  Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, Car.prototype); // slow!!
  return instance;
}
var Ferrari = new Car('Ferrari', 'Italy');
var fred = new Person();
fred.cars.ferrari = new Ferrari(1200, 300000);
```

Alternatively, you can add a method which will be used to "instantiate" your instances.

```
function Person() {
  this.cars = {};
}
function Car(make, country) {
  this.make = make;
  this.country = country;
}
Car.prototype.instantiate = function(currentPrice, miles) {
  var instance = Object.create(this);
  instance.currentPrice = currentPrice;
  instance.miles = miles;
  return instance;
};
var ferrari = new Car('Ferrari', 'Italy');
var fred = new Person();
fred.cars.ferrari = ferrari.instantiate(1200, 300000);
```

Comment: Thanks for supplying an alternative. If you don't mind me asking, is there any benefit to using this instead of the 'call' method?

Comment: @jamcd They are different approaches. `call` is used when subclassing, in order to call the super constructor from the extending one. But you want to instantiate instances, not a subconstructor. So the super constructor has already been called to create the instance you want to instantiate, and then there is no reason to call it again. The advantage of the approaches I provided over subclassing is that you don't need to know the car names (e.g. Ferrari) beforehand. From the question, I understood this was what you wanted, not subclassing.